# Loopback findOne where number is highest

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, loopback

I am using Loopback to get my data. i have the following table:

```
id, name, version_number
```

Now i wish to find the name where the `version_number` is highest.

So say i have the following data:

```
1, 'hello', 2
2, 'test', 1
```

I wish to find the record `1, 'hello', 2`

From the documentation, I can't seem to find anything that matches what i need. So can anyone tell me how I would do that?

Please note that i am not looking for a `find` function where we order by `version_number` i am looking for a `findMax` kind of function

Comment: @jarlh postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FETCH FIRST` combined with `ORDER BY` to find the row the the highest version_number:

```
select * from tablename
order by version_number desc
fetch first 1 row only
```

Comment: please note im using loopback

Comment: Does that mean you don't want an SQL answer?

Comment: i was looking for a loopback function that did this

Comment: If that's the case, the <sql> tag is somewhat misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
SELECT * FROM table t where 
   version_number IN (select max(version_number) from table v)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like that :

```
const findMax = (model, field) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    model.find({
      order: `${field} DESC, id ASC`
    }, (err, rows) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      resolve(rows.filter(row => row[field] === rows[0][field]));
    });
  });
}
```

as a remote method, hook, middleware, whatever fits your needs.